# removeAttr() after destroySlider() is not working - bxslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I have a section with items and it becomes a slider under 755px. So on window resize checking if that slider exists then destroy it (so that when someone resizes the window it will be resized properly).

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="slider">
          <div class="item">1</div>
          <div class="item">2</div>
          <div class="item">3</div>
          <div class="item">4</div>
          <div class="item">5</div>
          <div class="item">6</div>    
     </div>
</div>
```

Js

```
var slider;
jQuery(window).on('resize', function(){
    if(jQuery(window).width()  < 755){
        // slider code goes here
        slider = jQuery(".slider").bxSlider({   
            mode: 'horizontal',
        });
    }else{
        if(jQuery(".wrapper .bx-wrapper").length){
            slider.destroySlider();
            jQuery(".slider").addClass('destroyed_slider');

            jQuery(".slider").removeAttr('style');
            jQuery(".slider .item").each(function(){
                jQuery(this).removeAttr('style');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

But after destroySlider() I see some odd styles on the slider and on the items which really should not happen as destroySlider() should destroy everything, but anyways for solving it, removing style attribute from them but removeAttr() is not working.

The strange thing is that `jQuery(".slider").addClass('destroyed_slider');` is working, only removeAttr() is not working. Any ideas please?

Comment: Would you add your **HTML** code please

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want the slider to be removed when screen > 750? Currently you are recreating the slider infinitely on resize.

Comment: @MehdiBouzidi - added html code

Comment: @Obsidian - actually it works perfectly when you are not resizing the browser window but as long as it should work correctly on window resize, yes I want to remove/destroy the slider above 750px and then recreate if window size is less 750px.

Comment: I think you will find people are struggling to help you because you haven't provided the relevent information for them to do so. For example, you have not provided the html but it has no reference to `.bx-wrapper` which is what you are doing the check against in the script. I have ammended my answer below for you to try something else.

Comment: @Obsidian - I'm not sure how much you are familiar with the script, but you can have your own class for the selector (for me it is the `.slider`) and it is not necessary to have `.bx-wrapper` and it is not related to my question.

Comment: Then why is it in your question? How can we help you when you are only presenting half your code? We can only guess.

Comment: My question is simple - removeAttr() is not working right after destroySlider() function of bxslider library. I found some temporary solution and will post it soon. @Obsidian

Answer (score 0):

You are doing:

```
slider.destroySlider();
```

before you remove 'style', so when you do:

```
jQuery(".slider").removeAttr('style');
```

the element does not exist anymore therefore it has no style attribute.

**Try**

After `destroySlider` try to empty the `innerHTML` or `html()` in jquery:

```
jQuery("{parent id, not .slider}").html("")
```

This empties the parent element containing the slider element

Best